# Find the orthogonal complement

Tags: functional-analysis

Find the orthogonal complement of a set $A = \{f \in L^2(-1,1), \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx = 0\}$. What does the orthogonal projection look like?

Comment: You can write $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx$ in the form $\langle f,g\rangle$. If this isn't enough, do explain what obstacle you are meeting in this problem.

Comment: The integral over $(-1,1)$ is just the zero-th coefficient of the Fourier series of $f$.

Comment: @Fundamental, I know that $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx = <f,1>$, so it means that constant functions are fine, but what with others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that given any $x,n\in L^2(-1,1) $  with $n\neq 0$ there is a unique scalar $\lambda$ and $y \in L^2(-1,1)$ such that $x = \lambda n + y$ and $y \bot n$.

For existence, let $\lambda = { 1\over \|n\|^2}\langle n , x \rangle $ and
$y = x-\lambda n$. It is easy to check that $y \bot n$.

For uniqueness, suppose $\lambda_1 n + y_1 = \lambda_2 n + y_2$, or
$(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)n = y_1-y_2$. Taking the inner product with $n$ shows that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$ and hence $y_1=y_2$.

Let $A = \{x | \langle n, x \rangle = 0 \}$.

Suppose $z \in \operatorname{sp} \{n \}$ and $x \in A$, then we have 
$\langle z, x \rangle = 0 $ and so $z \in A^\bot$, hence $\operatorname{sp} \{n \} \subset A^\bot$.

Now suppose $z \in A^\bot$. Using the above result we see that we can write
$z = \lambda n + y$, where $y \bot n$. Since $y \in A$, we have 
$\langle z, y \rangle  = 0 = \|y\|^2$, and so $z = \lambda n$, that is
$A^\bot \subset \operatorname{sp} \{n \}$.

Hence $A^\bot = \operatorname{sp} \{n \}$.

Projection onto either $A$ or $A^\bot$ is accomplished as in the first paragraph
above.